# Git Autocompletion looks weird (and only half-functional)

Tags: linux, macos, git, bash, autocomplete

Following [these excellent instructions for enabling Git bash autocompletion in OSX](http://railslove.com/blog/2011/11/25/git-autocomplete-in-bash-on-a-mac/):

```
curl https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -o ~/.git-completion.bash
echo "source ~/.git-completion.bash" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I get the following output when I type "git <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>" at the command line:

[image: Output from git tab-tab]

Following multiple different tutorials produces the same result. Either I don't know the right search terms or there is just very little documented about this issue...

Anyone encountered similar issues implementing git autocompletion for OSX? Running Lion if that's important.

Comment: The weird `^[[00m` look like [ANSI color escape sequences](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html).  In your Terminal.app preferences > Settings > Advanced what's "Declare terminal as:" set to?  How about `env | grep TERM`?

Comment: The `^[[00` looks like some sort of shell completion for ANSI terminals. Are you using Terminal.app? Check under Terminal->Preferences... In the Advance section, check to see what terminal type you're set to (should be either "xterm" or "xterm-color". Also make sure that "Escape non-ASCII input isn't checked. Check the value of the $TERM environment variable too.

Comment: Results of `env | grep TERM`: TERM=xterm-color. In Terminal.app it says "xterm-256color".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a simple fix. I simply removed the following line from my ~/.bashrc file (as per [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=141415)):

```
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'
```

...and now it works like a charm :)

Comment: Better yet, replace it with `--color=auto`, as in siyuan's answer. That way you get colors in your grep without compromising the use of `grep` in pipelines.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. Using `export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto` instead of `export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'` could resolve this problem.